# How long does Account Association Disabled last?

Tags: support, status-completed, migration, user-accounts, linked-accounts

I have been seeing this in [my User Accounts tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/151244?tab=accounts) for the past 24 hours (well, almost).

> **Account Association Disabled**
>
> While the network is being migrated,
>   account assiciations to Meta have been
>   disabled.

(Note: Yes, it is account *assiciations*, you read that right. :)

This happens to all other user accounts as well.

**My question:** How long does it take for the network migration to complete so I can see those other related accounts in StackExchange sites?

Comment: Luk, i speil jyst fife thanj yu.

Comment: Yu aR weLKamD...

Comment: careful now... if Kevin's anything like Jeff, he'll show up at your house with a giant "i" and a speargun.

Comment: Ooh, I'm so scared! Come if you dare, I'll treat you with Nasi Lemak!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plan is for it to be re-instated next week.

But you know how these kind of things are, it could be delayed and only happen in 2 weeks.

Comment: What? 2 weeks?? oh well...

Comment: Btw, does this happen regularly? You all have a fixed schedule to do these?

Comment: @Gan Meta.SO is moving to a new datacenter, and apparently this needed to be disabled

Comment: I can see the User Account tab now. The network migration last for slightly less than one week. Just for the record. :)

Comment: Aww... Only 2 weeks? I would have expected 6-8 weeks...